# How to convert .svg to .eps?

Tags: vector, inkscape

I am using Inkscape to create .svg vector files. I wanted to convert it to .eps so that I could use it in Latex (unable to use .svg in Latex). Please recommend a free software to convert .svg to .eps.

Update: I did google for the question, but the closest answer I got was this SuperUser question:
[Converting between EPS and SVG format](https://superuser.com/questions/198460/converting-between-eps-and-svg-format)

I was hoping for a better answer. I was unable to install GS on my Windows 7 machine. Currently I email images to my friend who converts it on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In InkScape: FILE > SAVE AS > choose EPS from the format list.

Comment: @user9667 you should be able to click the ADD COMMENT to add comments. I'll add it here for you: UPDATE: The InkScape SAVE AS is not perfect and there may be some errors in the conversion. (Wanted to add this as a comment instead of editing the answer but there was no option for that) I used InkScape on Mac: FILE > SAVE AS > choose EPS from format list, while writing a paper which required EPS submission. However I found that there were some errors in the conversion.